# Jenkins Subversion post-commit hook with authentication - anonymous job read still required?

Tags: svn, jenkins, post-commit-hook

We are using Subversion 1.8.8 and Jenkins 1.509.4 (with the Subversion v2.3 plugin) for our many project builds.  Company policy requires authentication, so within Jenkins we are using LDAP security realm, and project-based security matrix for user global and also project authorization.  Our SVN post-commit hook talk to Jenkins by using an LDAP service account created just for this occasion.  When implementing this, I realized that in order for the hooks to actually trigger jobs, even with a valid username/password being sent, it was not enough to have that account listed as having full access to Jenkins on the security page; anonymous Job Read access was still required.  It was also noted that the service account did not need any explicit access at all. For the jobs in question, polling is enabled.  Both an explicit schedule (I tried H 0 1 1 *) and no explicit schedule were tried.

The side-effect of this configuration is that valid users of Jenkins can see every job on the server.  This is a problem as this presents users with 200+ jobs, and most users only care about a handful of them.

Is there a configuration that will allow authentication for a post-commit hook, without enabling ANY anonymous access within Jenkins?

For a reference, our post-commit hook looks like this:

```
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
UUID=`${SVNLOOK} uuid $REPOS`
PW_SCRIPT=/home/ci/bin/get_ci_pw.sh
if [ ! -f $PW_SCRIPT ]; then
    exit 0
fi
JENKINS_USER=ci
JENKINS_PW=`$PW_SCRIPT`
if [ "x$JENKINS_PW" = "x" ]; then
    exit 0
fi
if [ "x${UUID}" = "x" ]; then
    exit 1
fi
echo "${UUID} : ${REV} : ${REPOS}" >> /tmp/post_commit.out
/usr/bin/wget \
    --connect-timeout=5 \
    --tries=2 \
    --http-user=$JENKINS_USER --http-password=$JENKINS_PW \
    --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \
    --post-data "`${SVNLOOK} changed --revision $REV $REPOS`" \
    --output-document /tmp/post-commit-wget \
    http://ciserver:8888/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=${REV}
exit 0
```

In the above configuration, I was able to locate this information within the Jenkins logs:

> May 27, 2014 3:36:12 PM INFO
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh Refreshing
>
> org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@25e3951:
>   display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Tue May 27
>   15:36:12 EDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
>
> May 27, 2014 3:36:12 PM INFO
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext
>   obtainFreshBeanFactory
>
> Bean factory for application context
>   [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@25e3951]:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@9466053
>
> May 27, 2014 3:36:12 PM INFO
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
>   preInstantiateSingletons
>
> Pre-instantiating singletons in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@9466053:
>   defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy
>
> May 27, 2014 3:36:30 PM WARNING
>   hudson.scm.SubversionRepositoryStatus$JobTriggerListenerImpl onNotify
>
> No subversion jobs found
>
> May 27, 2014 3:36:30 PM INFO
>   jenkins.scm.impl.subversion.SubversionSCMSource$ListenerImpl onNotify
>
> Received post-commit hook from 47272b4f-b969-45fb-85a3-5cc10733bede
>   for revision 1,995 on paths
>   [mdeneaul/TIJ4/branches/1.1-SNAPSHOT/pom.xml]
>
> May 27, 2014 3:36:30 PM INFO
>   jenkins.scm.impl.subversion.SubversionSCMSource$ListenerImpl onNotify
>
> No subversion consumers for UUID 47272b4f-b969-45fb-85a3-5cc10733bede
>
> May 27, 2014 3:36:30 PM WARNING hudson.scm.SubversionRepositoryStatus
>   doNotifyCommit
>
> No interest in change to repository UUID
>   47272b4f-b969-45fb-85a3-5cc10733bede found

Answer (score 0):

Is your Jenkins JOB configured to Poll to the SVN ? 
Functionally a Post commit hook should not require polling from CI to SVN but you still need to configure the JOB to poll mode, can keep any value like daily, weekly or yearly. 
This way it opens up the Jenkins JOB to listen to the post commit call from SVN because by default it does not listen to these calls.

Comment: Polling is enabled on the appropriate jobs, with no set polling schedule. I'll adjust my question.

Comment: Did u try having a schedule like weekly or yearly? Does the post commit still require a read only user? Bcoz I am not passing any user details frm my post commit with such config and still my jenkins is secured..

Comment: Try setting a schedule along with the polling n post commit wont need a read only user

Comment: In a test environment, I enabled the user "ci" to have full admin access, and added a specific polling schedule of monthly in the job.  The job still would not build unless I enable anonymous job read access, which is what I have in production and is what I'm trying to fix.  I will add this and some additional information to the original question.